# cannot install do_postgres on debian wheezy, ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to install dm-postgres-adapter gem and it fails when installing do_postgres gem.

Cannot find headers for postgres.

```
checking for main() in -lpq... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for postgres.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I already installed postgres and libpq-dev from apt, but still postgres.h is nowhere in my system

Anybody knows which library is needed to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the missing library. If you encounter the same problem you need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install the `libpg-dev` package which contains the headers and sources.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I installed that already. I said in the question, I installed libpq, but I meant libpq-dev. Edited question to reflect that. You can see that libpq-fe.h is already there

Comment: @Tom what version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: I have installed 9.2 and 9.3 on different ports